# helper method included in a model produces "undefined local variable or method `config' for" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a quite complex helper method that is also needed to be in a model. I've done it with just including some helpers in my model, but the same approach is not working on Rails 3.0.7.

```
module ContentsHelper
  def content_teaser record
    # it uses image_tag, truncate, raw, and some others.
  end
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  include ActionController::UrlFor
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::RawOutputHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
  include ContentsHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def teaser
    content_teaser self.body        
  end
end
```

and the error information I have

```
undefined local variable or method `config' for #<Content:0x10bac7248>
app/helpers/contents_helper.rb:8:in `content_teaser'
app/models/content.rb:70:in `teaser'
```

any suggestion/advice?

Comment: I'd suggest you restructure your code - in general the helpers are supposed to be for views only.

Comment: @Ant Thank you the suggestion. But I really need it to do a particular job. The method does generate a teaser version of the content. I use it for both presentation and to store the teaser in the model for cache.

Comment: In that case I would do the work in a method in your model and then simply call that method from your helper?

Comment: @Ant That's a possible option but I'm not sure if producing html code in a model is a good approach. Anyway thanks for the suggestion. We decided to remove that feature for the other reason though. So I put this off for a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also got hit with the error working with Rails 3.1 RC

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `config'
```

Some Rails source tracing and I discovered the missing include ActionView::AssetPaths.

```
include ActionView::AssetPaths
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
```

Comment: In Rails 3.1.1 that causes this error: `in 'include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)` so I guess `AssetPaths` became a class.

Comment: @PaulAnnesley same here, works after adding `include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper` and `include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper` (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/pull/529)

Comment: @hakunin was encountering the same issue with Spree ecommerce gem's core tests, and this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @hakunin, that worked a treat! FYI: I found that I only needed `include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper`.