# Can't access image_tag from helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I would like to test the following helper module function:

```
module UploadsHelper

  def custom_img_tag(upload, width, height, id)
     if width > Upload::MAX_CROP_WIDTH
       image_tag(upload.photo.url(:original), :id => "box", :width => Upload::MAX_CROP_WIDTH, :height => (height*Upload::MAX_CROP_WIDTH/width).to_i)
     else
       image_tag(upload.photo.url(:original), :id => "box")
     end
   end

end
```

However when I run the following test:

```
describe UploadsController do
  include UploadsHelper
    describe "custom_img_tag(upload, width, height, id)" do
           before(:each) do
             @upload = Factory(:upload)
             geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(@upload.photo.to_file(:original))
             @width   = geo.width
             @height  = geo.height
           end

       it "should return the original image tag for an image that is not wider than  MAX_CROP_WIDTH" do
         #custom_img_tag(@upload,@width, @heigth, "cropbox" ).should == '<img id="cropbox" width="500" height="375" src="/system/photos/10/original/avatar.jpg?1311044917" alt="Avatar" style="display: none;">'
       end
     end
```

I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: custom_img_tag(@upload,@width, @heigth, "cropbox" ).should == '<img id="cropbox" width="500" height="375" src="/system/photos/10/original/avatar.jpg?1311044917" alt="Avatar" style="display: none;">'
     NoMethodError:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
```

Why do I get this error and how can I test this method?

Update:
I added the following to the spec test file:

```
include ActionView::Helpers
```

Which produces the following error:

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `config' for #<RSpec
```

How can I get rid of this error and what is the cause?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What does your `Factory :upload` look like? `You have a nil object` is a pretty straightforward error message... which of your objects in the `custom_img_tag` method is nil?

Comment: BTW You can do a quick check on things like this within a spec by just putting `puts @upload.inspect` or similar. It'll print to the console when you run the spec. Don't leave that in there afterward, but I find that can help locate issues sometimes when a spec is behaving strangely.

Comment: Thanks andrew I will have a look and use that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: OK I actually had to use puts and this is what it outputed: NoMethodError:
       undefined method `image_tag' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x00000103419e58>

Comment: You can't see the bounty link under the "Add Comment" link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [helper method included in a model produces "undefined local variable or method \`config' for" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290176/helper-method-included-in-a-model-produces-undefined-local-variable-or-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also got hit with the error working with Rails 3.1 RC

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `config'
```

Some Rails source tracing and I discovered the missing include ActionView::AssetPaths.

```
include ActionView::AssetPaths
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
```

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290176/helper-method-included-in-a-model-produces-undefined-local-variable-or-method, `AssetPaths` is now a class, so you cannot include it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why this would be, but my guess is that for some reason ActionView::Helpers must not be loaded in this spec. Try including ActionView::Helpers and see if that fixes it... The issue (from what you're reporting) is that when your `custom_img_tag` method gets called it isn't able to call `image_tag` for some reason.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I inlucded the ActionView::Helpers and now when I run the test I get this error:NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `config' for #<RSpec         any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what would trigger that. I'm definitely not an RSpec expert. This question might need a bounty to get answered.